# e-mails of all the accounts were blocked due to spamming activity of a single account in shared hosting

Tags: email-bounces

I have around 25 websites hosted on shared hosting environment. Somebody, who has also hosted a website on the same hosting server started spamming. Due to this spamming activity the shared IP got black listed.

Due the IP black listing and rated as High Risk by some black-listing authority, all the mails sent by the e-mail ids created on my websites are being bounced.

How to avoid these scenario and protect my websites from suffering for the wrong actions done by others? Is there any work around? Is there any technical solution so I can give seamless e-mail communication for my websites?

Comment: Since you aren't the server administrator, you can't do much of anything that we would suggest (and your question is also off-topic for that same reason). You may wish to visit our sister site [webmasters.se] and search for further ideas of how you can operate your email in a shared hosting environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use shared hosting to run a mail server. Seriously, that's just an incredibly bad idea. Anyone who shares that IP with you can impersonate your mail server. And how can you accept inbound mails if the IP is shared?

Doesn't your hosting provider offer an email service? It is well known that this doesn't work.